# Spring Boot + Mongo - com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'id' criteria

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Any ideas why I get this error when making a query:

`org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'id' criteria. Query already contains '{ "id" : "123"}'`

I'm using Spring Boot and Mongo:

```
fun subGenreNames(subGenreIds: List<String>?): List<String> {

        val results = mutableListOf<String>()

        var query = Query()

            subGenreIds!!.forEach{

                query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").`is`(it))

                var subGenreName = mongoTemplate.findById(it, SubGenre::class.java)

                results.add(subGenreName!!.name)
            }

        return results
    }
```

I have the class SubGenre set with:

```
@Document(collection = "subgenres")
data class SubGenre(
    @Field("id")
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add information about `it` parameter in the `findById(it,` call?

Comment: Hi - updated to show the full method

Comment: [Due to limitations of the BasicDBObject, you can't add a second '$and' - Mkyong.com](https://mkyong.com/java/due-to-limitations-of-the-basicdbobject-you-cant-add-a-second-and/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you need to use either

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").`is`(it))
var subGenreName = mongoTemplate.find(query, SubGenre::class.java)
```

or

```
var subGenreName = mongoTemplate.findById(it, SubGenre::class.java)
```

but not both.